# PHP script name from process ID

Tags: php, fastcgi, pid

Given a process ID for php-cgi (run as FastCGI on Linux), how can I get the path/name to the script it's running?

If it's *not* FastCGI, I can get the path/name from the process' environment in /proc/PID/environ, but when it's run using FastCGI, the script name is not passed in the environment. From the FastCGI web site:

> Instead of using operating system environment variables and pipes, the
>   FastCGI protocol multiplexes the environment information, standard
>   input, output, and error over a single full-duplex connection. This
>   allows FastCGI programs to run on remote machines, using TCP
>   connections between the Web server and the FastCGI application.

Doing an strace on the process, I can see it opening and closing the script file, but I need to get the name of the script that's already running. Someone mentioned php-status, but I don't have that, unfortunately.

Since this is for a security app, I can't just pass $_SERVER[SCRIPT_FILENAME] from the script because the script could just pass anything, unless I could get that in a way that the script itself couldn't fake.

This should be easy, but the way FastCGI does things is making it into a tough problem.

Any ideas welcome. Thanks.

Comment: not the most efficient, but you could capture stdout of a `top` command where you specify the pid.  or you could directly access the /proc folder and get the info from the corresponding proc file.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to do that, but I haven't had any luck with it. If it's not run using FastCGI, then I can get the path/name out of the environment, but FastCGI doesn't pass things that way. I also looked in the parent's /proc, hoping for some luck, but so far nothing.